# Targeting DOM Nodes Isn't Quite Working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following HTML markup and script is faulty, but I'm not getting why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>More Ways To Target Elements</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <div id div="div2">
      <p id="p1">Chicago</p>
      <p>Kansas City</p>
      <p>St. Louis</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var div = document.getElementById('div2');

    for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (div.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeType === 3) {
        alert(div.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML);
      }
    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried minifying the whole thing but I get the same results from the console, which says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null
```

Any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: `<div id div="div2">` invalid markup here

Comment: The invalid HTML isn't the only problem, but FWIW, the *reasons* it's invalid are: 1. `div` elements have no `div` attribute, and 2. If you provide the `id` property, it must have a non-blank value. `<div id div="div2">` gives the `id` property a blank value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems there:

1. Your HTML is invalid and you have no element with the `id` `div2` (`<div id div="div2">` should be `<div id="div2">`). That's what's causing the error you're starting out with.

   But once you fix it, you'll run into more errors:
2. Not all nodes have `childNodes`, only `Element` nodes do. Specifically, `Text` nodes do not. But you're assuming all of the child nodes of `#div2` are `Element` nodes. They aren't, some are `Text` nodes.

   If you only want to look at `Element` nodes in `#div2`, use `div.children` rather than `div.childNodes`. `children` only contains `Element`s, not other kinds of nodes.
3. You're assuming all of the children of `#div2` have at least one child node, because (if you implement #2 above) you're doing `div.children[i].childNodes[0].nodeType`. That will throw an exception if there are no child nodes, because `childNodes[0]` will give you `undefined` and you can't read `.nodeType` from `undefined`. You need a guard there.
4. `Text` nodes don't have `innerHTML`. If you want the text of a `Text` node, you use `nodeValue`.

With those changes:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div2');

for (var i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
  if (div.children[i].childNodes[0]) {
    alert(div.children[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <p id="p1">Chicago</p>
    <p>Kansas City</p>
    <p>St. Louis</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

***But***, if the goal is to show the text content of the children of `#div2`, I'd probably use `querySelectorAll` and use `textContent` (not supported on older IE) or `innerText` on the elements (which are not the same thing, but the differences don't matter here) instead, as it would be simpler:

```js
// Get the name to use (textContent isn't supported on older IE)
var propName = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText";
// Get the immediate children of #div2,
// alert their contents
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#div2 > *');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    alert(list[i][propName]);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <p id="p1">Chicago</p>
    <p>Kansas City</p>
    <p>St. Louis</p>
  </div>
</div>
```